# Prevent SIGALRM from interrupting waitpid()

Tags: c, signals, waitpid, setitimer

I'm trying to make my process `waitpid()` for a child process, but also print something every interval amount of time.

My current plan is to schedule an `itimer`, `waitpid()`, handle the `SIGALRM` printing, and stopping the timer when the `waitpid()` finishes.

The only part I can't figure out is preventing the `SIGALRM` from interrupting the `waitpid()`.

I've looked in the man pages and don't see any flags for this.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [`waitpid()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) returned `-1` and `errno` equals `EINTR`  just start over calling `waitpid()`.

```
pid_t pid;

while (((pid_t) -1) == (pid = waitpid(...)))
{
  if (EINTR == errno)
  {
    continue;
  }

  ...
}
```

Alternatively (at least for Linux) the return of `waitpid()` on reception of a signal could be avoided via the `SA_RESTART` flag set on installing signal handlers. For more on this please see here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to mask the signal before calling waitpid(), but then your alarm will be delayed until unblocked, or you have to check waitpid() return value and errno for EINTR